# Purpose of this custom resolve function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble puzzling this resolve function out...

```
function _resolve(){
    var $deferred = $.Deferred();
    return $deferred.resolve.apply($deferred, arguments).promise();
}
```

I see it being used like

```
    if (availableLanguages.length === 1) {
        return _resolve(availableLanguages[0]);
    }
```

and

```
        if (detectedLocale && availableLanguages.indexOf(detectedLocale) > -1) {
            // save the locale so the user does not get asked for it again
            return _resolve(detectedLocale, true);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `_resolve` function is a *shortcut* for creating kind of a *dummy* jQuery Deferred object, which is initially resolved. They should have rather called it for example `_createResolvedPromise` which would be more intuitive, but we always used to save some characters don't we.

In general this technique is needed when you have a function which returns a deferred, but in some cases you can have an early return with some value. In this case you cannot just return the value, because the caller expects a deferred, so you have to create a deferred object and immediately resolve it with that value. You can perhaps call these deferred objects *constant deferred objects* or so.

The `apply` is used to call the `resolve` with the optional arguments passed to `_resolve`. Those arguments will be passed to the `done` callback later on. See the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

Calling `promise()` on the deferred object is nothing more than wrapping it into a promise object, so that the consumer cannot call `resolve` for example. See the documentation [here](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/).

For example, let's assume we want to retrieve something via ajax, but also we cache the results.

```
var _cachedResult;
function getResults() {
  if (_cachedResult) {
    // for THIS line they made the _resolve shortcut, with which I could write _resolve(_cachedResult)
    return $.Deferred().resolve(_cachedResult).promise();
  }

  return $.ajax(...).done(function(result) {
    _cachedResult = result;
  });
}
```

The caller can use it like this.

```
getResult().done(function(result) { 
  // do something with result, which maybe came from the cache
});
```

Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

In short, it appears to be wrapping up various calls in a Promise/async fashion.

It's likely that `detectLocale` is an async function, and they're using _resolve to simply handle it in a synchronous manner. Your `_resolve` function is returning a `Promise`, which presumably the consumers of those return values are using.

I would expect to see something like this if you trace it up:

```
function getLanguages() {
    if (availableLanguages.length === 1) {
         return _resolve(availableLanguages[0]);
    }

    return new Promise(); // or something, unless it's checking for null outside
}

function doSomething() {
    getLanguages().then(languages => console.log(languages));
}
```